# Getting a best fit put onto the plot along with its equation

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, plot

So I have a data file that I have extracted the data from and made a graph, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a best fit to it along with a best fit equation. I always get an error message back saying "can't multiple a sequence to a non-int of type numpy.float64"

I have tried changing the b, m variable to a float, but that didn't work. I've tried changing the variables around that I knew were a float, still didn't work.

```py
import matplotlib #plotpackage
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') #graphicspackage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #might be a redunancy
import csv

from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit



abscissa = []   #coordinate systems
ordinate = []

with open('/home/jacob/Downloads/data.v3.txt', 'r') as datafile:
    plots = csv.reader(datafile)
    firstline = datafile.readline()
    for line in datafile:
        x, y, dy = line.split()
        abscissa.append(float(x))
        ordinate.append(float(y))

b, m = np.polyfit(abscissa, ordinate, 1)

plt.plot(abscissa, ordinate, label='Data line')
plt.plot(abscissa, b + m * abscissa, '-')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I should be seeing my plot, with a best fit line over it. Once I know I have the line, it should be easy to call the line back as an equation and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few areas that might be causing some issues you might want to check.

1. `polyfit` will return the slope then intercept--so you have `b` and `m` reversed.
2. `abscissa` is a list so you won't be able to perform arithmetic operations as you would an array. You can just cast it to an array. *This is likely why you are getting your error*.

Try something like this:

```
abscissa = np.array(abscissa)
m, b = np.polyfit(abscissa, ordinate, 1)

plt.plot(abscissa, ordinate, label='Data line')
plt.plot(abscissa, b + m * abscissa, '-')
...
```